# Using Connection File as Environment

Tags: arcpy, convert, export

I'm trying to automate a process that reads data from an enterprise GDB and outputs a shapefile to folder on a network drive. In attempting to do this, I realized I don't know as much about environments and workspaces as I thought I did.

Can I (and should I) use an SDE connection file as the environment? If not, can anyone suggest other ways for me to do this (if it's possible)? Code below.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:\Connections\SDE_Connection.sde"

input = "FeatClass"
output = "C:\Shapefiles"

arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(input, output)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use connection files as the environment.  This is really no different than specifying a variable for your enterprise database (sde) and then referring to that as your location when using your tools.  The environment setting just automates this - it tells arcpy to look in that location if you don't specify an absolute path.

So what you have in your code above is the same as this, except you can bypass the `os.path.join()` or equivalent to tell arcpy where your `FeatClass` is.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

myws = "C:\Connections\SDE_Connection.sde"

input = "FeatClass"
output = "C:\Shapefiles"

arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(os.path.join(myws, input), output)
```

As for the "should I" - it comes down to what you are doing, and the permissions you have.  If you have set your enterprise GDB as your environment workspace, don't get your inputs and your outputs mixed up

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(r"c:\temp\myshapefile.shp", "NewFeatClass")
```

this will copy my shapefile into the enterprise GDB, rather than

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("NewFeatClass", r"c:\temp\myshapefile.shp")
```

which will copy the feature class from the enterprise GDB to a shapefile.  If you forget to specify an output path in your tool it will attempt to output it into the path you specified in your environment workspace.

Comment: More specifically, a working connection file (with valid user/password having been saved or entered upon use) is considered a Workspace object.